# Cancelling GetSaveAsFilename

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have code, that only runs when a user chose "Save As". To do that and getting the new name of the file I'm using the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` function.

The problem I came across was a type mismatch while checking if the user clicked on Cancel when he did not do that.

Line that threw the error when Cancel was not clicked: `If saveName = False Then Exit Sub`

My working code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Not SaveAsUI Then Exit Sub
  Cancel = True

  'other variables
  Dim saveName As String

  saveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(filefilter:="Microsoft Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="Save as Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet")
  On Error GoTo RunTime13
  If saveName <> False Then
  On Error GoTo 0

  'other code

  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=saveName, FileFormat:=52
  End If
Exit Sub
RunTime13:
  If Err.Number = 13 Then Resume Next
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong, that I have to work around the Cancel button like this?

**Edit:**

I chose `Dim saveName As Variant` to be able to use `If saveName = False Then Exit Sub`

As Vityata mentioned I am in Germany and thus could have run into problems with the language, fortunately for me Vityata reminded me of the problem because I am in fact using Excel in English, but not all of my colleagues are, so my accepted answer might not have worked when they were using the workbook.

Comment: You've declared `saveName` as a string?

Comment: I feel stupid, I didn't think to use variant. Thank you CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've declared `SaveName` as a string, you need to check for `"False"`, not `False`.

```
If saveName <> "False" Then
```

Comment: VBA may be the 3. most hated language for quite some reasons, but the one above is not one of them - `?"False" = False` returns `True` in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

`OP`, I have some news for you - you are in Germany and thus I am about 99% sure you are using German Excel.

There the VBA is a bit translated, thus the `saveName` is translated to `Falsch` and not `False` as in the rest of the world. E.g. `CStr(False)` returns `Falsch`.

In your code write either of these three:

```
If saveName <> "Falsch"
If saveName <> False
If Len(saveName) <> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
Dim vSaveName As Variant

vSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", _
    Title:="Save as Macro-Enabled Worksheet")
If TypeName(vSaveName) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
'' otherwise continue with save...
```

The only time vSavename is a Boolean is when the user cancels, so this approach doesn't need to know how to say False in the user's language.